# Joining Sqlite table on Subqueries

Tags: sqlite, subquery

I'm trying to join a sqlite table based on an grouping column, 'year'. I've started with a select clause that returns all the years in the database, and now I want to subquery the same table for various statistics and join it based on the year. The following is what I have.

```
select strftime('%Y', `date`, 'unixepoch') as `year` from transactions as t

left join (
    select sum(amount) as `expenses`, 
    strftime('%Y', `date`, 'unixepoch') as `year` from transactions
    where type = -1 and user_id = 1
    group by strftime('%Y', `date`, 'unixepoch')
) as e on e.year = t.year

left join (
    select sum(amount) as `income`, 
    strftime('%Y', `date`, 'unixepoch') as `year` from transactions
    where type = 1 and user_id = 1
    group by strftime('%Y', `date`, 'unixepoch')
) as i on i.year = t.year

group by strftime('%Y', `date`, 'unixepoch');
```

When I try to run that sql statement, I get 'no such column: t.year'. Why can't I join based on the aliased column?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] in the shape of a few lines of `create table ...` and `insert ...`; also the desired output matching the sample data from the `insert`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table `transactions` aliased as `t` does not contain a column `year` (which is a derived column).
Change to this:

```
select strftime('%Y', t.`date`, 'unixepoch') as `year` from transactions as t

left join (
    select sum(amount) as `expenses`, 
    strftime('%Y', `date`, 'unixepoch') as `year` from transactions
    where type = -1 and user_id = 1
    group by strftime('%Y', `date`, 'unixepoch')
) as e on e.year = strftime('%Y', t.`date`, 'unixepoch')

left join (
    select sum(amount) as `income`, 
    strftime('%Y', `date`, 'unixepoch') as `year` from transactions
    where type = 1 and user_id = 1
    group by strftime('%Y', `date`, 'unixepoch')
) as i on i.year = strftime('%Y', t.`date`, 'unixepoch')

group by strftime('%Y', t.`date`, 'unixepoch');
```

I guess there are other columns from the joined tables that you want to return although not in the current code.
I think that this is what you want to achieve:

```
select 
  strftime('%Y', t.`date`, 'unixepoch') as `year` ,
  sum(case when type = -1 and user_id = 1 then amount end) as `expenses`,
  sum(case when type = 1 and user_id = 1 then amount end) as `income`
from transactions as t
group by strftime('%Y', t.`date`, 'unixepoch');
```

Comment: That second one actually did exactly what I wanted. I didn't know I could do that with SQL. It's not my primary language.